# "Underwriter" and "Underwritee"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

In other contexts, "interviewer" is the person conducting an interview and "interviewee" is the person being interviewed. Other examples of "-ee" are loanee, the person who receives a loan.

In my context, I'm contrasting the roles of the "underwriter", the person who underwrites a risk (e.g., insurance company) and "underwritee", the person who's selling the risk (e.g., insurance policy holder). Is "underwritee" a real word? A quick search through dictionary suggests that it's not. If it's not, what's the right word for the "underwritee"?

Comment: The insured. . .

Comment: ... or the proposer, if a quotation is being obtained.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this... thanks!